# dojo: create multiple floating panes w/ resize in border container

Tags: dojo, resize, containers, floating

I'm fiddling w/ dojo (1.4) and am having a problem programmatically creating floating panes (containing ContentPanes w/ dojo grids/graphs) inside of a title pane's borderContainer.

```
this._displayPane.contentBorderContainer.domNode.appendChild(reportFloater.domNode);
```

I can create multiple floating panes inside a border container but cannot get the resize handles to stay on the panes once the floating pane startup is called.  I am calling startup on the child containers before creating the floating pane.

Stepping through in the debugger, I can see the resize handle appear when the floating pane is inserted in the dom, but then when I call startup, the child content container is takes all the floating pane content area.  The resize handle is there (in the dom, not visible), and has zero width and lies outside the floating pane.

Any help greatly appreciated - I've looked at this too long!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be the lack of a parent container for the floating pane that caused the resize handler to have zero width and lie outside the floating pane's defined margin box.

Using a node list method to add the resize handler after the floating pane (created without a 'resizable' attribute) and adding it to the DOM (via nl.concat(this._displayPane.contentBorderContainer.domNode).addContent(reportFloater.domNode, 'last')),

I then created the resizeHandle (with 'activeResize' true and specifying the css in the style attribute).

May not be the most concise, elegant solution, but it works for me :)